# How to run "cut" command on csv using AWS Data Pipeline ShellCommandActivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-data-pipeline

Using AWS Data Pipeline ShellCommandActivity, I'm trying to run some pre-processing on a file that has way more columns in it than I want using the "cut" command to extract just the columns I want. I seem to be able to "grep" the file to an output file successfully. Whenever I try "cut", I get an empty file as output.

I've tested my cut syntax locally and it works in that environment.

Is "cut" available using the ShellCommandActivity method? If not, where can I find a list of available commands or how could I add this to the EC2 it is using to execute?

Comment: Additional information: I now realize that it is running, but the output is going into "StdOut" and I'm unclear why and how to handle that output file. I'm relatively new to UNIX/Linux. When I run locally using  a ">" to route output to a file, it seems to work fine. However, the Pipeline execution seems to route it to "StdOut".

Answer (score 0):

This was a stupid mistake and I'm sorry I posted this. It is just difficult to troubleshoot AWS (for me anyway.) The issue was that I had a carriage return before my redirect (">") so it wasn't catching that part. Once I removed the carriage return, the command executed as expected.